# Unable to access GeoServer from another computer in the same domain

Tags: geoserver, network

I installed GeoServer 2.5.2, GeoNetwork 2.10.3 and Tomcat 7 on my Windows 7 computer {MyComputer} in our company's network. Now I would like to access GeoServer, GeoNetwork and Tomcat from other computers in the network.

However, I could only access via the web browser GeoNetwork and Tomcat but not GeoServer.

**NO**  -  http://{MyComputer}.{domain}.com:8070/geoserver/web/

**YES** -  http://{MyComputer}.{domain}.com:8040/geonetwork/srv/eng/main.home

**YES** -  http://{MyComputer}.{domain}.com:8080

Is there any configuration that I missed?

Comment: DO you have a firewall, or something else that might block something on the 8070 port? secondly, when you say you cannot access, what exactly do you see? do you see a timeout error or something else?

Comment: Yes I have a firewall enabled. How do I set port 8070 opened? What I saw on the browser is "This webpage is not available" on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. I had to add a New Rule to the Advanced Firewall Settings for opening port 8070 for inbound traffic.

Comment: It's great that you shared how you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on which port your geoserver is running, then to open the firewall in linux use these 2 commands from root:

1. for e.g. if your port is 6789 on which your geoserver is running then use:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=6789/tcp –permanent
```

2. Reload the firewall

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```